# How to Handle jqGrid pager in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to Handle jqGrid Pager by own not jqGrid API

JqGrid All data store into cache but I want to not all data store into cache  i want store data user requirement row number.

- When I click next or previous button on pager that time call Action method and send data relative page number and row and display.
- And Update Page Number in Pager.

**My Html Code:**

```
    <div id="jqTable">
        <table id="jqGridTable"></table>
        <div id="jqGridTablePager"></div> 
    </div>
```

**My JS Code :**

```
    $("#jqGridTable").jqGrid({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUserList", "Account")',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['LoginID', 'Login Name', 'Group', 'Email ID'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'LoginID', hidden: true, index: 'LoginID', width: 300 },
        { name: 'LoginName', index: 'LoginName', width: 300 },
        { name: 'GroupID', index: 'GroupID', width: 200, sortable: false },
        { name: 'EmailID', index: 'EmailID', width: 300, sortable: false }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#jqGridTablePager', 
        loadonce: true
    });
```

Please Help me for this solution

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking but I think the problem you are experiencing is due to `loadonce: true`, which causes the grid to load only once and not call the server when changing pages. Try setting it to false or further describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks Alexandru Severin , You are right  I was change my jqGrid setting **loadonce: false**  so solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jqgrid options [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> loadonce - If this flag is set to true, the grid loads the data from
>   the server only once (using the appropriate datatype). After the first
>   request, the datatype parameter is automatically changed to local and
>   all further manipulations are done on the client side. The functions
>   of the pager (if present) are disabled.

If you are not planning to load all the data from the server at once then set this flag to false (or don't set it as all, as false is default)